# "The specified module can not be found" in C++/Cx VS2017CE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xaml, visual-c++

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. 
I'm doing a universal Windows program in Visual C++.

So I made my interface through XAML but the problem is when I add a c ++ source, no more user control is found.

Before I add "Database.cpp" It's ok

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPjyh.png)

But when I add my class

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSgSu.png)

This in my "Database.h"

```
#ifndef _DATABASE_H
#define _DATABASE_H


#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <string>

namespace GEOTAC
{
    //Structure contennant les informations de connexion à la base de données
    typedef struct 
    {
        std::string host;
        std::string db_name;
        std::string user;
        std::string password;
        std::string connect_timeout;
    } DB_Informations;

    class Database
    {
        public:
            Database(DB_Informations connexionInfo);

            void SetConnexionInformations(DB_Informations connexionInfo);
            virtual int Connect();
            void Disconnect();


            int ExecuteRequest(const char * request);

        private:
            PGconn* _connexion; //Instance de connexion à la base postgresql

            DB_Informations _coInformations;    //Contient les données de     connexion

            std::string ConstructConnexionString(DB_Informations     informations);

    };
}



#endif //_DATABASE_H
```

And this is the cpp code :

```
#include <pch.h>
#include "Database.h"

using namespace GEOTAC;

Database::Database(DB_Informations connexionInfo)
{
    SetConnexionInformations(connexionInfo);
}


/*
    * Modifie les informations de connexions à la base de données
*/
void Database::SetConnexionInformations(DB_Informations connexionInfo)
{
    _coInformations = connexionInfo;
}

//Connecte l'instance de connexion à a base de données
int Database::Connect()
{
    int retour = 0;
    /*
        Retours :
            0 : Connexion réussie
            -1 : Erreur de connexion        
    */

    _connexion = NULL;


    _connexion = PQconnectdb( ConstructConnexionString(_coInformations).c_str() );

    ConnStatusType statusCo = PQstatus(_connexion);

    if (statusCo != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        retour = -1;
        Disconnect();
    }


    return retour;
}

//Deconnecte l'instance de connexion de la base de données
void Database::Disconnect()
{
    PQfinish(_connexion);
}

int Database::ExecuteRequest(const char * request)
{
    PGresult * res = PQexec(_connexion, request);

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


/*
    * Construit la chaine qui permet d'initialiser la connexion a la base de données
    * a l'aide de la structure passée en paramètre.
    */
std::string Database::ConstructConnexionString(DB_Informations informations)
{
    std::string out = "host=";
    out += informations.host;

    out += " dbname=";
    out += informations.db_name;

    out += " user=";
    out += informations.user;

    out += " password=";
    out += informations.password;

    /*out += " connect_timeout=";
    out += informations.connect_timeout;*/

    return out;
}
```

Do you have an idea why the designer crash ?

Comment: I targeted a little more problem and it comes from libpq-fe.h. If I do not include it, I have no more errors. The problem is that I need it

Comment: The problem come from "_connexion = PQconnectdb("");". I don't know why..